Continuous functions wrt railway metric
On $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have the french railway metric:
$$ d(x,y) = \cases{\lVert x-y \rVert \text{ , if } x,y,0 \text{ are collinear} \\ \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert \text{ , else}}  $$
This induces a topology that is finer than the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was interested on what this does to the continuous functions.
I gave some thought about the functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, which are the curves and I think we should only have the ones that move on a single one-dimensional subvectorspace for intervals which partition $\mathbb{R}$ then returning to $0$ at some point and going to another 1-dim subvectorspace. (When we move freely in space, we can take the preimage of halflines cutting the curve (those are open) and we would get singletons.
For the functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I reckon we should be looking like this: For every 1-dim subvectorspace $U$ let $f_U: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous be given and then we can lay them in the $\mathbb{R}^n$. This includes the continuous functions wrt the standard topology.
For the functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ I have no clue. Maybe someone can help here and also share input for the thoughts on the functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, maybe proof or other functions that are not mentioned by me.
Thank you in advance!

Please give a reference like this one.

In the definition of the metric at the beginning of the post, aren’t two points always collinear?

Sorry! I used the term without any thoughts. What is meant is that the points are on one line to the origin, so $x=\lambda y$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Thank you for the comment! I added $0$ to the condition.

Note that all spaces $\mathbb R^n, n>1$, (equipped with this metric) are homeomorphic to each other. To test continuity of a map from such $\mathbb R^n$ you indeed just test continuity on every line segment emanating from the origin. With this in mind, your 2nd paragraph pretty much describes the behavior of all continuous functions $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$.

How can you prove the homeomorphy?

Because it feels like it should be true, just uncountably many lines connected in one root but i cant see a map.

They are even isometry: Take a bijection $f$ between the sets of lines through the origin, $L_j\mapsto L_{f(j)}$, and use a linear isometry $L_j\to L_{f(j)}$. This will define an isometry $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$. BTW, if you want me to see your comment, you have to "ping me" (@Moishe Kohan). Also, I was wrong when I said that a map is continuous if and only if it is continuous on every line segment through the origin.
